# The new icon on the topbar on stackexchange.com doesn't have a dropdown menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stackexchange.com

On [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com), there seems to be a new icon on the topbar:

[image: Image showing new icon on topbar on stackexchange.com with no dropdown]

From the image above, you can see that I've clicked on the (rightmost) icon, but there doesn't appear to be any dropdown menu associated with it...

Is this a work in progress, or a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

Comment: Yeah I mistook this for the site switcher a second ago and was surprised to see it. Curious what the purpose is. Maybe just an accidentally-merged dev test?

Comment: I'm known for not clicking the achievements button but never found the self-discipline to not click the inbox. Just wow, if that isn't staged.

Comment: @Spevacus it does have a click handler: `onclick="return false"` ....

Comment: Most likely future change leaking by mistake to production. At least it does not harm any existing functionality. :)

Comment: It looks like an unfinished feature for Teams. Given that popovers require Stacks controller not available on stackexchange.com. If transplanted to an account with teams, it (mostly - for some reason, the /preference link is not relative) works as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbfxS.png

Comment: @Oleg huh. Teams, it's always teams. ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Oops. This dropdown has been removed from stackexchange.com now.

We're doing some reworking of how we handle user profiles on Teams and this WIP top bar change accidentally made its way to the Stack Exchange portal.

We learned that the Stack Exchange top bar works in mysterious ways and we'll try to avoid breaking it in future!

Comment: While you are at it, speaking as a moderate Teams user - you might want to consider removing the outline from the icon, it does not fit well with the established icon style on the topbar. The dropdown can be opened by simply clicking on the icon as other icon buttons do.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for the feedback. This is experimental at the moment so we have WIP / "programmer art" while we're iterating on things here.

Comment: Of course, Dion, just wanted to note that while we are at it :)

Comment: Welcome to Meta, where staff get some well deserved rep!

Comment: That menu [has appeared in another place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379235/348196).

Answer (score 14):

Looks like it is still a work in progress that got deployed (accidentally?).

Inspecting the element, looks like it should display a pop-over menu (named `popover-example`) that contains 3 elements:

- Back to your Team (links to `/`, i.e. `https://stackexchange.com/`; might be shown because this account is part of more than 1 Team)
- Account settings (`https://stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current`; currently not working because there is no user preference on the network account, only works on per-site account)
- Log out (`https://stackexchange.com/users/logout`)

Considering all of this, it is still unclear if the menu list is already final or not, and/or if this icon should be shown on the network topbar instead of per-site topbar in the first place.