# Weird profile icon on topbar on Insights

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, stack-overflow-for-teams

This is very similar to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378713/579398), but on a different domain. The top bar on [insights.stackoverflow.com](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey) has a weird profile icon. Unlike the previous bug, this one actually kinda works. Here's what you see after clicking on it:

[image: A menu with 3 options: "Back to your Team", "Account settings", "Log out"]

"Back to your Team" goes to the Insights homepage, not your Team. The other menu items work as expected. Either the "Back to your Team" item or the whole menu should be removed.

Comment: another strange thing is that clicking the stack exchange logo doesn't open the site selector and instead takes you to stackexchange.com

Comment: In fact, none of the other icons that usually open a dropdown are working as expected. Maybe some javascript is broken?

Comment: @CaveJohnson not broken, it was copy&pasted from Teams, so since it's not in Teams, strange things happen.

Comment: Quoting the staff's answer, "the Stack Exchange top bar works in mysterious ways" :) I am not sure how it managed to pop up there of all places, though.

Comment: Really cool design of the animation on the top of that page!!

Comment: Related (bug that was fixed recently): [The new icon on the topbar on stackexchange.com doesn't have a dropdown menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378713/348196)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. Indeed, this is the same bug that was reported for StackExchange a few weeks ago, but in a different flavor.

It is now removed from insights.stackoverflow.com and hopefully from everywhere else!