# Why are tooltips for bare links to SE posts (in comments) not capitalized despite the actual posts being capitalized?

Tags: support, comments, capitalization

When posting links to SE posts in comments, where links are not converted to links with titles, the tooltips for those links are not capitalized.

For example, this is a bare link with an uncapitalized tooltip:

[image]

And [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332398/rep-cap-reached-but-not-counted-towards-legendary-badge) is the actual post with the title capitalized:

> [image]

Note that the bare links I'm referring to above are the ones which are copy-pasted from the address bar or  by right-clicking the title. Bare links which are copy-pasted from a question or answer's [Share box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvzU3.png) do not have tooltips as they don't have slugs.

Comment: This bare URL has an uncapitalized tooltip: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379235/weird-profile-icon-on-topbar-on-insights

Comment: There is a slight difference between the /q/ and /questions/  url. The latter is the canonical url while the former is just a shortcut that returns a 302 to instruct the browser to then fetch the canonical url.

Comment: test comment to see if slug matters https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379235/and-now-for-something-completely-different

Comment: test comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379235/Weird-profile-icon-on-topbar-on-Insights

Comment: Cross-mentioned on MSO here: [Hovering link to question show the wrong title based on link itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424381)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not capitalized because that is not the title of the question that is shown in the tooltip.

It is the so called slug at the end of the url with the `-` replaced by a space. By design the slug is always lower case. And the slug itself is irrelevant for the correct working of the link. You can add any slug you want:

Try this comment:

> `test comment to see if slug matters https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379235/and-now-for-something-completely-different`

leading to this tooltip:

> [image: tooltip]

and the link still works.

Comment: Thanks, rene.. that makes sense. But slugs *can* be capitalized, no? https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcK03.png | https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tf9X.png

Comment: @Justin slugs can be capitalized, but that looks like a different question of why *all* generated URLs on Stack Exchange are in lower case (example: your name and my name on profile links, which are also slugs).

Answer (score 2):

I just made the userscript [SmartPostLinks](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SmartPostLinks.user.js) to solve this. On top of question title, it will also display: post type, author, author rep, date created, last activity date. It will also work in chat, and chat transcripts. It also generally works for post links from other sites on the Stack Exchange network (except the Hot Network Questions, which I disabled it otherwise it will make too many requests - one per unique site).

Userscript **SmartPostLinks** ( [source](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/SmartPostLinks.user.js) | *[install](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/raw/master/SmartPostLinks.user.js)* )

#### Screenshots

**Before (1):**
Misleading post slug resulting in incorrect title attribute

[image]

**After (1):**
Link text and title attribute corrected by Smart Post Links, and displays more post info

[image]

**Before (2):**
Unknown short link (also known as share/referral link), requiring you to click on it to view post title/details (no title attribute set - *no effect if you hover over such links*)

[image]

**After (2):**
Post title for short link is now displayed upfront in link text, and more post info in title attribute

[image]